# Spring test failing with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing

I have a config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("mypackage");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

}
```

and I have a test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)
public class UserServiceTest {


    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;


    @Before
    public void initDB(){

        MyObj my = new MyObj();
        my.setValue(1000L);

        myRepository.save(my);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        assertEquals(4, userMoneyRepository.findAll());
    }

}
```

and my error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getXmlMappingBinderAccess(MetadataSources.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:168)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:52)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at config.WebConfig.entityManagerFactory(WebConfig.java:48)
    at carx.config.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2f198977.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$0(<generated>)
    at carx.config.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2f198977$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d53a2482.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at config.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2f198977.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 65 more
```

at `config.WebConfig.entityManagerFactory(WebConfig.java:48)` I have  `factory.afterPropertiesSet();`
What should I do? I use this config when I start application with Spring boot and it works.
I have runtime database when my application works. And I want use this configuration for tests.

Comment: What JDK version are you using?

Comment: And what Spring Boot Version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Gradle add this :

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
```

if you use Maven add this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```